# Email password forgotten

Tags: password

I remember the password to logon Ubuntu operating system.  However, I can't remember the password for my email on the system. There are some emails that I need to forward to another laptop. When I select the email I want and hit forward, I get the following message:Unable to authenticate to IMAP server.  `IMAP command failed:(AUTHENTICATION FAILED)  Please enter the IMAP password for(my email name goes here) on host imap.gmail.com`. I have gone through all the passwords I can remember, but no luck finding the right one. Is there an area on Ubuntu operating system where I can fine my email password? I have been trying for about 5 hours and I can't find where it is.

Answer (score 0):

First: If you had access to gmail on microsoft then its the same as that.  Go back to your microsoft and access your email. While there change your email password to your gmail account.  Make a note of the gmail password.  Return to Linux OS and access your email with the same password.

You may have a phone that accesses gmail as well, use it to change your password if OS PC method fails.

Access to gmail is not dependent on OS; it is dependent on google mail (gmail).

Second: gmail has a feature to restore your account using security measures you put in place according to gmail security policy settings.  This is not an OS issue its a documentation issue.  How do you document your passwords for all your online passwords?